# Google Tag Manager Event in Analytics as Goal

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

When I us Google Tag Manager for tracking a Link-Click, it shows up as an Event in Google Analytics. So far so good.
Let's say in GTM: Category is {{Event}} / Action is {{Click Event}} and Label is {{Page Path}}

Now I will have this Event as Analytics Goal (Conversion) - not AdWords. So Am I right, I have to set up in Analytics the Goal again but can't us the variables from GTM?
So the Category must be like "Test" Action "Click" Label "Link Click" or can I say, track my GTM Event in Analytics as Goal like linking them thogheter?

In GTM you can't set up an Analytics Goal right? You have to do the Event and then go to Analytics and make it as a Goal, true?

Comment: Not totally getting your question, but the way it works is you need to create an event tag that is triggered by, let's say, a link click. That event tag has at least a category and action, which can be anything you want. Then in GA you can set up an event goal that converts if at least the category matches that from your GTM event.

Comment: I think you got my question ;) so if the GTM Event, let's say a link click, has the Category "LinkClickXY" and the Event is automatically tracked by GA, the only thing I have to do is to set up a Goal in GA with the Category of "LinkClickXY" and my Goal is ready? Category of Event and Category of Goals has to be the same. But GA can't use variables like GTM, right?

Comment: No, GA doesn't use variables like GTM. Whatever you have pushed into the dataLayer as the event category and action, you can use for your Event tag. You can then use the same event category and action for your GA event goal. Or if it's just a link click event, then you won't necessarily have an event category or action pushed to the dataLayer. In this case, you just use whatever you want in your event tag (which, again, is triggered by the link click).

Answer (score 2):

if you are using GTM to tracking event. it is not necessary to give {{Event}} or any predefined Macro(variables) as Event Category , Event Action or Event Label.
It is entirely upto you . You can give any string/ name the create goal in google analytics..

Link if you are click on any download link
Event Category will be 'Download Link',
Event Action you can choose as {{Click text}} or {{Click URL}}
and Event Label as  {{{Page Path}}
 after that at the time of goal creation you can use 'Download Link' as Goal Category and leave action and label. it will help you to tracks all download link as well as link url and on which page this event occcurs.. so on